# How to choose seed in flood/fill algorithm

Tags: algorithms, mesh

I was able to draw to the outer airtight boundary of hole. Now I would like to implement interior flood/fill algorithm. To get an internal seed, only one method comes to my mind which is testing neighbors of red cells for ray casting. However, I would like to know is there a faster method.

[image]

Comment: Are you working on spider webs? And is your whole always convex?

Comment: No I don't always work on spider webs nor the outer boundary always convex.

Comment: When your boundary is non-convex raycasting is no solution to finding the interiour. How do you get the boundary? Maybe you can generate normals as well? Depending on the size of your areas a last resort would be to fill inside and outside and see which one terminates.